# why can not I see the value (status) of safe_mode and register_globals

Tags: php

why can not I see the value (status) of safe_mode and register_globals

I use this code from php.net:

```
echo 'display_errors = ' . ini_get('display_errors') . "\n";
echo 'register_globals = ' . ini_get('register_globals') . "\n";
```

The above example will output something similar to:

display_errors = 1, 
register_globals = 0

but i gеt this:

display_errors = 1, 
register_globals =

register_globals is off but i get nothing instead of [0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) (zero)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting `false` to a string results in an empty string and those values *are* booleans:

```
> echo gettype(ini_get('register_globals'));
boolean
```

The documentation of `ini_get()` is indeed misleading about this.

Comment: i get string as type not boolean :/ ok. Can you tell me how do I check if register_globals is on/off

Comment: If you have to check for it you are usually doing something wrong... assume it's off and do not use `extract()` etc. to create globals!

Comment: will not use it, just want to check it out without phpinfo. I`m trying to create code that verifies the minimum requirements for a simple CMS.

Comment: 10x ThiefMaster :)

and this is what i need:

 $register_globals = (bool) ini_get('register_gobals');

or


 $register_globals = (int) ini_get('register_gobals');

so simple :D

now i get my 0 !!!